# How to mock libraries used inside service/controller while running cucumber

Tags: go, cucumber, acceptance-testing

I am using cucumber to run acceptance tests.
I am using the following `Zendesk` library to call methods to create tickets, and view them
https://github.com/nukosuke/go-zendesk

I want to know while writing acceptance tests how to mock this library. I am using dependency injection design to test this on a unit test case. But I don't know how I can mock it while acceptance tests.

I know that in case of acceptance tests, you should actually run it without mocking, but let's say that there is cost associated with this zendesk api for now, and I don't want to actually call zendesk api behind the scenes.

How can i mock the library here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mock a library or module or package, you can only mock a type.

Mocking any type works the same way:

1. Create an interface that covers the methods you use from that type
2. Change functions that take that type to take the interface instead
3. Create a mock type that satisfies the interface for use in testing
4. Pass the real type in production code, and the mock in test code